# how to add bootstrap date picker to tabulator header filter

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, innerhtml, tabulator

Tried putting in inner Html

```
 var dateEditor =  (cell, onRendered, success, cancel) => {
 var abc = '<div id="xyz" bsDatepicker></div>'
 return  abc;
    }


 columns: [
{ title: "Expiration Date",  field: "expirationDate", headerFilter:dateEditor}
]
```

`
         still not working .
         I need to add datepicker to header filter .

`       tried using normal input date type

```
<input type=date />
```

```
  `   the value is not getting filtered even though format is correct.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML [column formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-column),

```
{ title: "Expiration Date",  field: "expirationDate", headerFilter:dateEditor, formatter:"html"}
```

Comment: but that gives just an input box in all the rows for a grid.It will not give in the header .I need only in header.However even if i use the formatter date picker is not triggered.

Comment: Ask a new question and put your working demo code in a JSFiddle